# how can i select exactly "Candy"

Tags: moovweb

How to select a tag which have "Candy" exactly?

```
<div class="abc">
       <a>Candy</a>
       <a>Candy Chocolate</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('//a[.="Candy"]')
```

It selects only first anchor tag which exactly contains text "Candy"